# How to get records for top parent in a DataSet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been given a dataset, which has the data in the below format.

I need to return the category details for a given category. If Keyword is not present for the category then need to return top level parent's keywords. the top-level parent is the category for which parent category is -1.

so for example for category 202, it should return Teaching as the keyword. and expected output should be
a comma-separated string.

> ParentCategoryID=201, Name=Operating System, Keywords=Teaching

[image]

I am getting the records from the below code.

```
string queryString = "SELECT [Category Id],[Parent Category Id],[Name],[Keywords] FROM [dbo].[Categories]";

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConnection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Categories");
```

I am able to write a logic to get the top parent in the list from the below code. but I am not able to write it according to the requirement for the dataset.

```
public long GetParent(long category)
{
    var element = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Category == category);

    if(element.ParentCategory == -1)
    {
        return category;
    }

    return GetParent(element.ParentCategory);
}
```

**Note**: there can be millions of records in the table.

Comment: Its not clear what you need. Modify your sql query to have this logic in the database or to modify the DataSet so you update it with the Keywords from the top-category if necessary. If the former you need to include much more, starting with the used RDBMS and all tables including their schema. If the latter you have to say why your code doesn't work if you simply loop all rows.

Comment: I need to handle this in C# not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following recursive method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static DataTable dt = null;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Category Id", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent Category Id", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Keywords", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 100, -1, "Business", "Money" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 200, -1, "Tutoring", "Teaching" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 101, 100, "Accounting", "Taxes" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 102, 100, "Taxation"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 201, 200, "Computer"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 103, 101, "Computer Tax"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 202, 201, "Operating System"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 109, 101, "Small Business Tax"});

            DataRow row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<long>("Category Id") == 202).FirstOrDefault();
            DataRow parentId = GetParent(row);
            string results = "";
            if (parentId != null)
            {
                results = string.Join(",", parentId.ItemArray);
            }
        }

        static DataRow GetParent(DataRow row)
        {
            DataRow parent = null;
            long pCategory = row.Field<long>("Parent Category Id");

            DataRow parentRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<long>("Category Id") == pCategory).FirstOrDefault();

            if (parentRow != null)
            {
                parent = GetParent(parentRow);
            }
            else
            {
                parent = row;
            }

            return parent;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here is testing for -1

```
       static DataRow GetParent(DataRow row)
        {
            DataRow parent = null;
            long pCategory = row.Field<long>("Parent Category Id");

            DataRow parentRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<long>("Category Id") == pCategory).FirstOrDefault();
            long parentCategory = parentRow.Field<long>("Parent Category ID");

            if (parentCategory != -1)
            {
                parent = GetParent(parentRow);
            }
            else
            {
                parent = parentRow;
            }

            return parent;
        }
```

Comment: Top level is decided based on the parent category id value -1

Comment: My null work the same since there is no category with id -1.

Comment: I added solution testing for -1.